# Installing security updates

Tags: updates

To update packages, I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get uprgade
```

but it never finds security update automatically and I get this notification:
[image]

How do I install security update using `apt`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` works within certain restrictions thus not all upgrades are installed.  Use `man apt-get` to view those restrictions, where you'll note `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` performs all upgrade does but without the restrictions that are placed on 'upgrade' alone.

Comment: @guiverc yes it does. Thank you.